# DataContext is not getting set inside Custom Button with Path Data

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, windows-phone

Hello I am trying to make a custom Button with PathData inside it. So far I have managed to view the Path inside it. But my Button is not taking MVVM Commands.

**Custom Button XAML**

```
<Button x:Class="My_Class.CustomControls.MyButtonWithPath"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480">
    <Grid>
        <Path  Data="{Binding}" Name="path"/>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

**Button Code Behind**

```
public partial class MyButtonWithPath : Button
{
    public MyButtonWithPath()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private static string _pathDatay;
    public string PathDatay
    {
        get { return _pathDatay; }
        set { _pathDatay = value; }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PathDataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PathDatay", typeof(string), typeof(MyButtonWithPath), new PropertyMetadata(pathDataCallback));

    private static void pathDataCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _pathDatay = (string)e.NewValue;
    }
}
```

**Usage In XAML**

```
<converters:KeyToValueConverter x:Key="conv"/>
<custom:MyButtonWithPath PathDatay="{Binding ConverterParameter=tv, Converter={StaticResource conv}}" />
```

**Converter**

```
 public class KeyToValueConverter : IValueConverter
 {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            return Utils.GetPathData(parameter.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception c)
        {
            throw c;
        }

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Utils Class**

```
public static string GetPathData(string key)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        dictionary.Add("tv", "etc etc etc......");
        return dictionary[key];
    }
```

**The Problem**

Whenever I am writing a Command in the Usage of the Button, it shows a not found error as it looks for the command inside my Custom Button NOT my MainViewModel(FYI I have a ViewModel named MainViewModel where I will put the Command related codes)

**My Guess**

I am setting the DataContext of the Button to itself with this "this.DataContext=this;" But if I omit this line then the Path does not show. Please guide me to set these things correctly

**Solution**

Given below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, `this.DataContext=this;` this line is the problem.
You typically dont use databinding for setting the look of the custom control. Instead you should set the `Name` of `Path` and set its `Data` property on initialization. You can do this by overriiding `OnApplyTemplate`:

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
    Path p = GetTemplateChild("path") as Path;
    p.Data = ...
}
```

Comment: In my case I am using p.DataContext=this; it is working!

Comment: what if I want to bind some text to a textblock inside the template? My question did not include it but I have a path and a textblock, I can set DataContext of the path, but if I write TextBlock tbx=GetTemplate("tb") as TextBlock; and then  tbx.DataContext=this, returns null

Comment: As I said, you shouldnt use DataContext inside the custom control. You shouldnt rely on hardcoded properties of the DataContext either. What you should do is add a dependency property on the custom control (e.g. Text) and bind that to the TextBox inside via `TemplateBinding`.

Answer (score 0):

I messed up with the code, @Domysee guided me the right way. My corrections--

**Custom Button XAML (Not Needed)**

**Button Code Behind, Usage In XAML, Converter, Utils (Same as Before)**

**Additional Part (StyleTemplate)**

```
 <Style x:Key="MyButtonWithPathStyle" TargetType="CustomControls:MyButtonWithPath">
      <Setter Property="Template">
           <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="CustomControls:MyButtonWithPath">
                   <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <Path x:Name="path" Data="{Binding}" DataContext="{TemplateBinding PathDatay}"/>
                   </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>     
         </Setter>
   </Style>
```

That's it! DataContext="{TemplateBinding PathDatay}" did the trick! Thanks everyone